# SQL Generated Joins with VARCHAR Casting of Decimals

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Generator in C# which allows users to pass in parameters which specify a table to join to, and which keys to join on.

Given the flexibility, and the fact that SQL sometimes didn't cast the field appropriately, the query ended up like so:

```
SELECT * FROM [SourceTable] AS [src]
INNER JOIN [JoinTable] [join1] ON CAST([join1].[someField] AS VARCHAR(5000)) = CAST([src].[otherFIeld] AS VARCHAR(5000))
WHERE [blah] = 'blah'
```

This has worked for quite some time, until it was required that the `someField` column on `JoinTable` be changed from a float to a decimal.  So now instead of `'1234' = '1234'` working as expected, we get `'1234.00000000000' = '1234'` which of course fails.

The biggest kink which is stopping me from a quick fix is that that fields don't have to be numeric.  They could very well pass in fields that join on `lastName` or something, and so I can't just TRY_CONVERT to float or something.

The second kink is that this is a join, not just a select, so I don't know the repercussions of putting a bunch of logic in a join, or if that's even possible.  Otherwise I wonder if I could do an IsNumeric type check and, if true, tryconvert to float, then cast to varchar, otherwise just cast to varchar?

We are using SQL Servers between 2014 and 2016

Comment: What do you mean by `SQL sometimes didn't cast the field appropriately` ? Isn't the query generated by the `c#` application ? You can check the data type by querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `sys.columns` and act accordingly

Comment: why don't you cast both fields to decimal ?

Comment: What is the datatype is used on join fields?

Comment: So you are always casting everything to varchar in joins in your sql generator, even if both columns are of the same type?

Comment: @Squirrel When you join on two columns of different types, SQL casts one of them to try to match the other as intelligently as it can during execution.  Some of the types being passed in were odd and caused the SQL to fail completely, so the query generator just forced a cast to varchar.  But now we're in this situation.

Comment: @santoshkumarPithani - The field types are known by the consuming application, but not by the generator itself.

Comment: @Evk the consumer of the generator module might know whether or not the fields are numeric, but the generator module itself doesn't even know that it is SQL, let alone the types of the fields being named.  Otherwise I'd have high-level type checks (numeric, date, string) and generate appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [SourceTable] AS [src] 
    INNER JOIN [JoinTable] [join1] 
    ON (CASE WHEN isnumeric('join1].[someField]')=1 
        then  CAST(CAST([join1].[someField] AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(50))
         ELSE 
             CAST([join1].[someField] AS varchar(50)) end) = 
      (CASE WHEN isnumeric([src].[otherFIeld])=1 then  CAST(CAST([src].
      [otherFIeld] AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       ELSE  CAST([src].[otherFIeld] AS varchar(50)) end)
      WHERE [blah] = 'blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Otherwise I wonder if I could do an IsNumeric type check and, if true
>   , tryconvert to float, then cast to varchar, otherwise just cast to
>   varchar?

Yes you have to do it exactly like this.cast both side of join to same data type.

```
SELECT * FROM [SourceTable] AS [src]
INNER JOIN [JoinTable] [join1] ON CAST([join1].[someField] AS VARCHAR(5000)) = CAST([src].[otherFIeld] AS VARCHAR(5000))
WHERE [blah] = 'blah' and ISNUMERIC([join1].[someField])=0 and ISNUMERIC([src].[otherFIeld])=0
union ALL
SELECT * FROM [SourceTable] AS [src]
INNER JOIN [JoinTable] [join1] ON CAST([join1].[someField] AS float) = CAST([src].[otherFIeld] AS float)
WHERE [blah] = 'blah' and ISNUMERIC([join1].[someField])=1 and ISNUMERIC([src].[otherFIeld])=1

declare @i decimal(10,4)=1234
declare @ii varchar(400)='1234'
--this won't work
select cast(@i as varchar(400)),@ii
-- this will work
select cast(@i as float),@ii
```